# Setting Text in Label from Web-Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to set some text which is coming in web-response to a label. Here is my response from web-service.

```
{
success = 1;
"user_post" = (
            {
        "associated_since" = "02 December 2015";
        "company_name" = "Amartam";
        "user_email" = "xxxx";
        "user_name" = "xxxxxxx";
        "user_phoneno" = 000000;
    }
);
```

I am trying to set the value of `user_name` in a `label`, but got only `(` in the label. Here is the code which I have tried.

```
    NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];
    NSDictionary *userPost =[response valueForKey:@"user_post"];
    NSString *userName  = [userPost valueForKey:@"user_name"];
    self.customerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userName];
```

Comment: why use stringWithFormat: when you already got the user name  in userName.
self.customerNameLabel.text = userName; :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *userName  = [[[response objectForKey:@"user_post"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"user_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

your `user_post` is array containing dictionary.

so you need to get the array and get the desired dictionary from those array.

```
NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];
NSArray *userArray = [response valueForKey:@"user_post"];
NSDictionary *userPost =[userArray firstObject];
NSString *userName  = [userPost valueForKey:@"user_name"];
self.customerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userName];
```